# Zeroing one or more matrix rows or columns

Tags: math, matrix, symbols

I have a full matrix of numbers. On a computer, I  can easily set with zeroes a row or a column.  I would like to know how I can represent this operation symbolically in a mathematical expression.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics and mathematical notation, not about programming. As such it would be better suited to the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For a `n x n` matrix `A` and with

```
e = ones(n)
e[k] = 0
```

matrix multiplication

```
A*diag(e)
```

zeros the k-th column and

```
diag(e)*A
```

zeros the k-th row